# How can i set encoder mode at stm32 h7?

Tags: c, arm, stm32

I'm trying to get encoder data to my stm32 h7 and display counter value through uart.

I can see counter value 0 through my uart terminal but counter value never goes up...

I'm using encoder mode.
Please, help me to do this

```
static void Encoder_init(void)
{
    RCC->APB2RSTR &= ~(1 <<  1);
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 1);   //TIM8 clk enable
    TIM8->CR1 &= ~(1 << 0);     //tim8 disable
    TIM8->SMCR |= (0x03 << 0);  //SMS set
    TIM8->CCER &= ~(1 << 1);    //CC1P
    TIM8->CCER &= ~(1 << 5);    //CC2P
    TIM8->CCER &= ~(1<<3);      //CC1NP LOW
    TIM8->CCER &= ~(1<<7);      //CC2NP LOW
    TIM8->CCMR1 |= (1<<0);      //CC1S
    TIM8->CCMR1 |= (1<<8);      //CC2S
    TIM8->PSC = 0;              //prescaler zero
    TIM8->ARR = 0xFFFF;
    TIM8->CR1 |= (1 << 0);      //tim8 enable}
}

void tEncoder(void *pvParameters)
{
    uint8_t encoder_data;
    char buf[4];
    char val;

    RCC->AHB4RSTR &= ~(1 << 2);
    RCC->AHB4ENR |= (1 << 2);
    GPIOC->MODER &= ~(0x03 << 12);
    GPIOC->MODER &= ~(0x03 << 14);
    GPIOC->PUPDR |= (1<<6) | (1<<7);

    Encoder_init();

    while(1) {
        vTaskDelay(1000);
        if(encoder_data!=TIM8->CNT) {
            encoder_data = TIM8->CNT;
            int2str(buf, encoder_data);
            uart7_buffer_putstr(buf);
            SystemPrint("tEncoder counting\n\r");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your code listing in the question first: You should replace all those *magic number expression* like `~(1 << 1)` with the corresponding speaking macros like `RCC_APB2ENR_TIM8EN`, which you find in a header like `stm32h743xx.h` (or similar, depending on the particular STM32H7 you're using. This way, it is possible to see (without a longer study) what you are trying to achieve, and you'll get sooner and better answers.

Comment: Please improve the question to assist us who want to provide a suitable answer without re-developing the entire program for you (or perform a research in the ref manuals to guess what you are attempting by which code line): (1) Please create a **minimal example** first - you don't need your UART to get the encoder/TIM running. (2) Please replace all the magic number bit patterns by speaking macros (check out header files like `stm32h743xx.h` for macros like `RCC_APB2ENR_TIM8EN` instead of `(1 << 2)`, for example). I downvote and flag the present question for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You cleared the MODER register but never set an Alternate function mode. According to [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) page 578

```
GPIOC->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODE6_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODE7_1); // Set mode to Alternate Function 2<<12; 2<<14;
```

And you never cleared and set alternate function low register (for pins 0-7) [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) page 582. The AF3 should be used according to this [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h747xi.pdf) page 95 for STM32H747XI.

```
 GPIOC->AFR[0] &= ~((0xFUL << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_Pos) | (0xFUL << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_Pos)); // Clear 15<<24; 15<<28
 GPIOC->AFR[0] |= (0x3UL << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_Pos) | (0x3UL << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_Pos); // Set AF3 for PC6 and PC7 3<<24; 3<<28
```